# Convert varchar to datetime in sql query where caluse and select

Tags: mysql, datetime

I am storing '2017/03/31/5 06:34:45.66' in Timestamp column having varchar32 as datatype.

```
CREATE TABLE `ABC` (
                    `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                    `TimeStamp` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
                    `Name` varchar(255)
                   ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=30821 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;`
```

How can I convert `2017/03/31/5 06:34:45.66` to datetime in select query and how can I do date range search using >= or <= for `2017/03/31/5 06:34:45.66`?

```
SELECT str_to_date(TimeStamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') 
from ABC 
where str_to_date(e.`Timestamp`, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s' ) >= '2016-09-19 00:29:27'
    AND str_to_date(e.`Timestamp`, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s' ) <= 2016-10-19 00:29:27
```

The above query returns NULL for Timestamp value .

Appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: You need quotes around the last datetime in your where clause.